# Compare two hashes by value to get keys/values where the 2nd is greater

Tags: perl

I have code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

#Coder: pavel69

open FILE1, "/home/stackovershroom/0/28.12.txt" or die;
my %dec28;
while (my $line1=<FILE1>) {
 chomp($line1);
 (my $plu28, my $count28) = split / /, $line1;
 $dec28{$plu28} = $count28;
}

open FILE2, "/home/stackovershroom/0/29.12.txt" or die;
my %dec29;
while (my $line2=<FILE2>) {
 chomp($line2);
 (my $plu29, my $count29) = split / /, $line2;
 $dec29{$plu29} = $count29;
}

print Dumper \%dec28;
print Dumper \%dec29;
```

Output:

> ```
>      $VAR1 = {
>      '3203100' => '7',
>      '3467390' => '14',
>      '3017931' => '19',
>      '3312878' => '1.806',
>      '3362576' => '56',
>      '3173204' => '23',
>      '3335495' => '6.377',
>      '202' => '30.848',
>      '2161067' => '13',
>      '3356411' => '6',
>      '3483437' => '6',
>      '3359188' => '11',
>      '...' => '...' #yet more 500 strings!
>      };
> ```

> ```
>     $VAR1 = {
>      '3153446' => '89.480',
>      '2062513' => '9',
>      '3386209' => '8.379',
>      '3195682' => '17.266',
>      '3411129' => '18',
>      '3154498' => '4.916',
>      '2043226' => '12',
>      '...' => '...' #yet more 500 strings!
>      };
> ```

I want to compare two hashes for searching keys from %dec28, values of which were incremented (from %dec29).

For clarity, in %dec28 I have:

```
'209198' => '2'
```

in %dec29 I have:

```
'209198' => '13'
```

Need to get all (only) incremented values for %dec28 when compare %dec28 <=> %dec29 (Increment values contains in %dec29). I was only able to get new keys/values that occur in %dec29

Minimal example:

```
%dec28 = (
         '3091212' => '1',
         '2093334' => '74',
         '209' => '5.600',
         '1947754' => '3',
         '3130087' => '6');

%dec29 = (
         '3091212' => '4',
         '2093334' => '60',
         '209' => '13.844',
         '1947754' => '9',
         '3130087' => '6');
```

Need to construct new

```
%increment_values = (
         '3091212' => '4'
         '209' => '13.844'
         '1947754' => '9');
```

It is possible? How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
# For each key in %dec28
for my $k (keys %dec28) {
  # If the same key exists in %dec29
  # And the %dec29 value is greater than the %dec28 value
  if (exists $dec29{$k} and $dec29{$k} > $dec28{$k}) {
    # Print something useful
    print "$k: $dec28{$k} -> $dec29{$k}\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but there are ways to compare parallel keys in two hashes.

Go through all the keys of one hash and check if those keys are in the other hash:

```
foreach my $key1 ( keys %hash1 ) {
    next unless exists $hash2{$key1};
    ... Do whatever you need to do
    }
```

If you want the larger values, you might assign just those to a separate hash:

```
my %larger;
foreach my $key ( keys %hash1 ) {
    next unless exists $hash2{$key};
    next unless $hash2{$key} > $hash2{$key};
    $larger{$key} = $hash2{$key};
    }
```

Or, you can get the common keys without doing anything:

```
my @common_keys = grep { exists $hash2{$_} } keys %hash1;
```

You can expand the `grep` to be more specific:

```
my @larger_keys = grep { 
    exists $hash2{$_} && $hash2{$_} > $hash1{$_}
    } keys %hash1;
```

Once you have the interesting keys, you can easily get a smaller hash of just the interesting pairs:

```
my %larger = 
    map { $_ => $hash2{$_) }
    grep { ... }
    keys %hash1;
```

With v5.20 or later, you can use [key-value slices](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/07/perl-5-20-introduces-keyvalue-slices/) (reusing the keys we extracted earlier):

```
use v5.20;
my %larger = %hash2{ @larger_keys };
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the new hash keys (`dec29`).  If the key exists in the old hash (`dec28`), compare the 2 values.  If the new value is greater, add it to the `increment` hash.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;

my %dec28 = (
         '3091212' => '1',
         '2093334' => '74',
         '209' => '5.600',
         '1947754' => '3',
         '3130087' => '6');

my %dec29 = (
         '3091212' => '4',
         '2093334' => '60',
         '209' => '13.844',
         '1947754' => '9',
         '3130087' => '6');

my %increment_values;
for my $k (keys %dec29) {
    if (exists $dec28{$k}) {
        if ($dec29{$k} > $dec28{$k}) {
            $increment_values{$k} = $dec29{$k};
        }
    }
}

print Dumper(\%increment_values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compact solution that can be a one-liner.

```perl
%day1 = ('3091212' => '1',
         '2093334' => '74',
         '209' => '5.600',
         '1947754' => '3',
         '3130087' => '6');

%day2 = ('3091212' => '4',
         '2093334' => '60',
         '209' => '13.844',
         '1947754' => '9',
         '3130087' => '6');

%incremented_values = 
  map { exists $day1{$_} && $day2{$_} > $day1{$_} ?
    ($_, $day2{$_}) : ()
  } keys %day2;
```

Now you showed the key values as strings.  If you need to preserve them as pure strings without numifying them, you'll need to copy the values.

```perl
%incremented_values = 
  map { exists $day1{$_} && (my $v2=$day2{$_}) > (my $v1=$day1{$_}) ?
    ($_, $day2{$_}) : ()
  } keys %day2;
```

HTH